# Fully removing an item from VB.NET Listbox control

Tags: wpf, vb.net, listbox

I'm trying to create a media player with playlist support in Visual Basic.NET 2012.
The playlist is a listbox control.
All is good until I have to clean the playlist and insert new songs (by New Open Dialog) or I want to delete a single one.

The problem is that `ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString)`
does not delete the path from listbox. It only disappear from the Listbox but when I add another item, clicking it just play the item that was deleted.
Let's say that we have 10 songs in playlist. If I delete all and I add other 10 songs, none of them will play! Each one will play one of those deleted.
I have tryed:

```
Try
  For i As Integer = (ListBox1.Items.Count - 1) To 0 Step -1
  ListBox1.Items.Remove(ListBox1.Items(i))
  ListBox1.Refresh()
Next
Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

And `listbox.items.clear`

Same thing happens!
Any help?

Comment: You should just repopulate the underlying list that the ListBox is bound to... if you're doing things properly.

Comment: ? I use openfiledialog to populate listbox

Comment: This doesn't look like wpf, so if it's WinForms, tag it appropriately.  An empty try-catch is definitely wrong.  And the code you posted doesn't help since you are basically saying `ListBox1.Items.Clear()` doesn't clear the box.  You need to document this problem better.